# Helping out with type error

Tags: python-3.x

so I have this code that takes a password input and gives it a score to show how good or bad the password is. whenever I try running it, it gives me the following error  message and I don't know what it means.

---

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        22     print("this password is worth",points,"points")
>        23 
>   ---> 24 write_password()
>
> in write_password()
>        12     askpassword = "askpassword".strip().lower()
>        13     for triple in triples:
>   ---> 14         if triple in askpassword:
>        15             points += -5
>        16     for char in askpassword:
>
> TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not list

And this is the code :

```
def write_password(): 
    points = 0 
    #askpassword = input("enter in a password. only use the chasricters")
    #char = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM"
    askpassword = "asdf"
    char = ["qwertyuiop","asdfghjkl", "zxcvbnm"]
    triples = []
    for chars in char:
        for i in range(len(chars)-2):
            triples.append(char[i:i+3])
    askpassword = "askpassword".strip().lower()
    for triple in triples:
        if triple in askpassword:
            points += -5
    for char in askpassword:
        if char in askpassword:
            if len (askpassword) >= 8:
                points = points + 1
            else:
                print("no points")
    print("this password is worth",points,"points")

write_password()
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The specific meaning of your error is quite straightforward. When you check if something is in a string in Python, it requires that that something is a string. In your case it is a list. You can not check if a list is in a string.

Printing out triples before your line `for triple in triples` will shed some light on your mystery and I suspect something is wrong in the code above.

> [['qwertyuiop', 'asdfghjkl', 'zxcvbnm'], ['asdfghjkl', 'zxcvbnm'], ['zxcvbnm'], [], [], [], [], [], ['qwertyuiop', 'asdfghjkl', 'zxcvbnm'], ['asdfghjkl', 'zxcvbnm'], ['zxcvbnm'], [], [], [], [], ['qwertyuiop', 'asdfghjkl', 'zxcvbnm'], ['asdfghjkl', 'zxcvbnm'], ['zxcvbnm'], [], []]